# How do I parse data from a Get-WMIObject query into a string?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have the following line of code...

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem | select-object username
```

It returns (redacted with placeholders)...

```
@{username=DOMAIN\jsmith}
```

What needs to be done to remove the padding and give me a "plain" readout of `DOMAIN\jsmith`?

For bonus points, how do I parse that value into just `jsmith`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to expand the property to get the value of `username` instead of a custom object with the property `username`. Try

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem | select-object -expand username
```

To get the username only, try:

```
(get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem | select-object -expand username).Split("\")[2]
```

You may need to use `[1]` instead of `[2]` at the end depending on your OS. In Windows 8, you need `2`, while in Windows 7(and older I think), you need `1`.

Comment: Perfect, it works! Do you happen to know how to tokenize that out to remove the domain portion?

Comment: It's a string. It can be `split`.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help everyone. I ended up doing `$_.split("\") | select-object -last 1`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount | where -property name -eq jsmith | select Name
```